# Get the id of url in controller

Tags: magento2

So im trying to get the id from url which look like this "catalog/category/edit/key/3fe130e5c0d9110729ff37ef34801a53362cca59c5b2ce91c0bffc59bf699b51/**id/147/**"

I want to know if that is possible? I have almost tried everything from google. Nothing works!

Answer (score 0):

In controllers and blocks you have direct access to the request object.
Try this code

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$categoryid = $data['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```